# Android apk problem

Tags: java, android

When i create one apk from one machine and try to install into a device .it successfully get installed .But when i try to connect the same device to another machine and try to deploy same application from different machine.It doesnt allow me .I need to uninstall the application and then it works correctly .What is the issue for that .What i need to do to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide us with the output from console or the terminal prompt. There is usually an error, telling that the Application is already install, and you have to use the -r re-install option, OR that the apk has been signed with a diffrent certificate/key.

If its none of the above, please provide whatever error/output you get... If there is no more info on the output, please start the Dalvik monitor (ddms) and see what happens via the log...

Comment: I have not found any option which says reinstall the application in ecipse IDE for android.I feel when i am just building the application from eclipse it just creates the apk for me .I need not to sign the apk.Ideally i would like to ask if it does internally.?

Comment: What does the Android Console in Eclipse say? Make sure it's set to "Android" output... Eclipse alway use the re-install option...Are all your project files equal, or do they just share the same package name? And also... What does the ddms log tell you when you hit Run button?

Comment: Ideally i think it happens when i switch platforms i.e, windows and linux ...It says "cant delete temp files".